# listing 'Administrators' group members with Python

Tags: python, wmi, admin

I need some assistance in retrieving the list of admins in the Administrator Group in Windows Server 2008 Computer Management window.

This code does something similar to what I want, it pulls the local Users from the Computer Management window:

```
import win32net

def GetUsers(IP):
    print IP
    print win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(IP,'none',0),
    return

servers ={'server1', 'server2' }

for CurrentIP in servers:
    print GetUsers(CurrentIP)
```

This generates the following:

```
server1
([{'name': u'$admin'}, {'name': u'zzGuest'}, {'name': u'BladeLogicRSCD'}], 3, 0) None
server2
([{'name': u'$admin'}, {'name': u'zzGuest'}, {'name': u'BladeLogicRSCD'}, {'name': u'ArcGISWebServices'}], 5, 0) None
```

Surely with this win32net module it is possible to get into the Admin group... Grateful for any help I can find here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with that both lists the members of the Admin group, AND prints them in a clean fashion:

```
import win32net

def GetUsers(IP):
    print IP
    accounts = []
    #print win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(IP,'None',0)
    a =  win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(IP,'Administrators',3)
    for rows in a[0]:
        accounts.append(str(rows).split(":")[1][3:-2])
        print str(rows).split(":")[1][3:-2]
    #print accounts

servers = {'server1', 'server2'}

for CurrentIP in servers:
    GetUsers(CurrentIP)
```